# How to deal with frequent faults in plugs

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

In my house I see faults with Plug or Tube light once in a month.

- Here is an apple laptop plug and it has become useless (
- there was an extension box plug and it caught on fire
- there was a plug of DTH antenna that became useless.

I had to replace 4 tube-lights so far which are not even two years old.

Other than the above macbook's plug I have another Mac book I don't know whether charger is gone or laptop is gone.

One more thing to add.

One of the rooms tripper goes off one in a while.

[image]

My house wiring is quite simple

[image]

[image]

[image]

FYI:

I invited one of the electricians to check out why this happens and fix this.

He said everything looks good and couldn't find anything wrong.

So I'm confused now.

if everything is alright why this has happened any ideas ?

I have decided to take below precautions:

- Install SPD(Surge Protection Device)
- I think GFCI is there in my circuit box which I have shown in the above picture if not install one
- CAFCI for any ARCs
- I'm going to check if all sockets are properly grounded to earth
- I'm going to check if neutral is connected properly
- I'm going to replace ordinary extension box with MOT based extension box.
- I'm going to see if the SPURs are having fuse junction box.

Should I do anything else.

Comment: Before you do anything, remove the flammable liquids from the panelboard area.

Comment: Hmm, why is that area wood? Shouldn't the panel be inside a metal box?

Comment: @RobertChapin - aye aye sir :)

Comment: @Nelson - I think to prevent electrical shock just in case electrical leak

Comment: Plugs becoming "useless" usually means someone has been abusing them, eg unplugging them by pulling on the cables.

Comment: Are you comfortable with measuring the tension of your plugs? Do you have an CAT3 rated multimeter?

Comment: Why do you have two meters? Hopefully there wasn't a mixup with their respective circuits

Comment: @keshlam - The plug is no longer working due to short circuit or over-current I don't know why But I have to replace the plug

Comment: @Martin - It's 3 house building. There's one 3-phase meter and two 1-phase meter respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3-phase.

So you are just as vulnerable to a [Lost Neutral from the utility as Americans are](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg).

If you have a loss of neutral from the utility, the voltage on your three phases will begin to bounce around.  Voltage will no longer be 230V to ground anymore, but will be more or less - as little as zero and as high as 400V.

If your house and other houses around have their own ground spikes/rods, and you bond neutral to them, this will limit the deviation somewhat and keep it closer to normal voltages.  However if your house does not have that, then neutral voltage will bounce all over the place, often exceeding 230V by a lot, and potentially frying equipment.

This problem can be spotted by 1 or 2 hot wires being below 230V while 1 or 2 are above 230V.  Generally this problem is with the power company's supply, but a problem in your panel could also solve it.

it doesn't help that in some places, there are no local ground rods and the utility provides neutral and ground separately, but originate them from the same wire.  When this wire breaks it creates a PEN fault.  There is equipment that will detect and protect you from PEN faults. It does this by comparing the voltage from hot to neutral on all 3 phases, and interrupting when they become different.

Comment: Could you let me know why the plugs and tube lights have gone bad ?

Comment: @CuriousMan because most appliances designed for 230V can't survive 400V for very long at all.

Comment: Is there any way to find if there's neutral loss ? I should use the multimeter and measure the volt is it ?

Comment: @SimonB - Even though it's 3 phase , the voltage is 230v only I checked it. My house electrician have given 3 phase to take higher load of electricity for all the electronic appliances

Comment: @CuriousMan 3-phase AC will have two different voltages phase-to-phase and phase-to-neutral.  In Europe, that's 400V phase-to-phase and 230V phase-to-neutral.  At least, it should be 230V if your neutral is working properly.

Comment: @SimonB absolutely, that would do it.  Hooking a 230V appliance phase-phase to a 400V supply will have a bad end.   In America our big industrial power (the stuff we run light rail and Superchargers from) is 277/480V, only about 20% hotter than your 3-phase there.   Our career electricians who work in homes will not touch the stuff, and defer it to specialty industrial electricians, who wear flash gear [and treat it with great fear and respect.](https://youtu.be/6hpE5LYj-CY)

Comment: @SimonB - That makes sense , 3 phase has two voltage phase if 230V phase fails another one would be 400V.. this can only happen when the neutral is lost and certainly I agree this would burn the appliance.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Is it possible the current was lost on one phase voltage i.e neutral is lost for a moment or energy didn't come in one phase as a result 400V phase got activated and burned the appliance and later on the original 230v phase started working as a result of energy coming in or neutral suddenly started working again ? I am mostly trying to understand how it burned the appliance at one point of time and it tripped then after turning the tripper on the problem didn't happen there after at least for a week or month

Comment: @CuriousMan typically a European transformer is 3-phase and serves an entire neighborhood.  That means you are unlikely to be the first to discover the problem. Could be someone else discovered it, then called it in, and it was fixed before you even knew about it.

Comment: yeah what you are saying makes sense. Thanks